# Android notification makes phone lag

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarm, foreground-service

I'm developing an app where users can create routines and set reminders for these routines.

I use alarms scheduled by AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver to call a foregroud service that sends a notification by using the notification manager. Here's some code:

```
    // Mark as completed
    Intent markAsCompletedIntent = new Intent(this, RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.class);
    markAsCompletedIntent.putExtra(RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.ROUTINE_ID, routineModelId);
    markAsCompletedIntent.putExtra(RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.ROUTINE_REMINDER_ID, routineReminderModelId);
    markAsCompletedIntent.setAction(RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_BROADCAST_MARK_AS_COMPLETED);
    PendingIntent markAsCompletedPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, routineReminderModelId, markAsCompletedIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    // Dismiss the notification
    Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.class);
    closeIntent.putExtra(RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.ROUTINE_ID, routineModelId);
    closeIntent.putExtra(RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.ROUTINE_REMINDER_ID, routineReminderModelId);
    closeIntent.setAction(RoutincoBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_BROADCAST_CLOSE);
    PendingIntent closePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, routineReminderModelId, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    if (!routineModel.Description.equals("")) {
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_appiconnotifications)
                .setContentTitle(routineModel.Caption)
                .setContentText(routineModel.Description)
                .addAction(0, "MARK AS COMPLETED", markAsCompletedPendingIntent)
                .addAction(0, "DISMISS", closePendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    } else {
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_appiconnotifications)
                .setContentTitle(routineModel.Caption)
                .addAction(0, "MARK AS COMPLETED", markAsCompletedPendingIntent)
                .addAction(0, "DISMISS", closePendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    }

    Intent openIntent = new Intent(this, RoutineReminderActivity.class);
    openIntent.putExtra(RoutineReminderActivity.RRA_ROUTINE_ID, routineModelId);
    openIntent.putExtra(RoutineReminderActivity.RRA_ROUTINE_REMINDER_ID, routineReminderModelId);
    openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    PendingIntent openActivityIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, routineReminderModelId, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(openActivityIntent);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(routineReminderModelId, notification);
```

On some devices while this notification exists in the notification drawer the phone is acting very laggy. It takes a very long time to activate the phone screen, to view the notifaction drawer, to unlock the phone. On some phones it works perfectly fine.

The phone that lags has Android 30 on it. If the notification is dismissed the phone starts working normally again.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the **specifications** of the device that is laggy and monitor **RAM** and **CPU** usage of the device, before, after and during your app runtime, speatially the RAM usage, maybe Android 30 is putting too much pressure on device and that is causing the issue.

In General the issue that are seen on some devices and not on another are caused ether by the difference between  **Android Versions** and their resource handling methods or bottleneck between **Hardware** and **Software** on same OS version on different devices.

You can monitor device resource usage ether by Android Studio's own resource monitor tool **["Android Profiler"](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)** or third party **Resource Monitoring Apps** found on Google Play.

If there is a process or function in your App that causing the resource leak you can fix it easily by detecting it from android profiler but if the issue is caused by OS Resource handling or Hardware and Software bottleneck you should skip that device.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a issue with the data leak within your app notification code .You can use android profiler . And you can also do some refactoring around your UI code for the notification . Some time when the notification bar is too many components to load it usually behave differently.Try to check with device screen size and UI re-sizer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by lowering the `android:width` & `android:height` for my notification's small-icon's vector asset.

The original size for my vector asset was 800dp x 800dp. Android Studio recommended me to change it to 200dp x 200dp so I tried that, and the lock screen lag disappeared.

There was no visible difference in my notification's small-icon after making this size change.